# How to skip combinations to guess string (python)?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a 20 byte string, from which I take 5 arrays of four bytes (first four bytes = array 1, etc.).

I have to convert each array into decimals through a specific function.

This way, I'll end up with 5 ints.

I have to add these 5 ints and reach a specific number (4863101420).

Do you have any idea of how to guess one possible combination of the 20 original chars that - going through the process of dividing into arrays and decoding into ints - will add up to 4863101420, without going through something like itertools.combinations_with_replacement?

Since I have 20 possible chars and each is one out of 94 possible chars (printable asciis), it could take a while to compute a string that adds up to 4863101420.

Any insights ?

The function I'm using to convert the char into int is:

```
def convertCharToDec(charInput):
    firstByte = format(ord(charInput[0]), "x")
    secondByte = format(ord(charInput[1]), "x")
    thirdByte = format(ord(charInput[2]), "x")
    fourthByte = format(ord(charInput[3]), "x")
    convertedHex = firstByte + secondByte + thirdByte + fourthByte
    return int(convertedHex, 16)
```

Comment: there are many, many, many combinations that add up to your number. Just pick one and reverse engineer it? Is your "hash" function reversible? For example, your number divided by 5 is 972620284; assuming all arrays are identical. What string does that correspond to?

Comment: By 20 byte string, do you mean 20 characters long string?

Comment: Well, add the first four (from what ever source they come) and the fifth will be `4863101420 - your_sum`.

Comment: Please post your specific function for converting array into decimals

Comment: @MohitC It is a 20 byte string, not a 20 characters long string. For this reason I am sticking to printable ascii characters.

Comment: post code in the question.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The function isn't reversible. If I convert 972620284 into chars, I'll end up using non printable asciis (using the function I just posted above).

Comment: if it is irreversible you got yourself a hash-function from the output of which (i.e., the number), you **cannot** guess the input (i.e., the string). You have to brute-force it and look for all possible collisions. Use the trick @KlausD. mentioned.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That's my point. I don't think I can skip brute-forcing - which was the actual question above (can I skip brute-forcing?).
I didn't quite get Klaus's trick. I need to add the five converted arrays to reach 4863101420. If I add the first four, how come the fifth will be my sum (4863101420) ? PS: I can't display any value equal to zero with the function I'm using (which would make things easier).

Comment: You can't find strings leading to a combination via one way hashing function without brute-forcing. Thats certain.

Comment: Are you considering "printable" to be the range 32-126? I'm unclear if you decided yourself to only use that range or you have to.

Comment: @KlausD. My source is a 20 byte long string (for instance: 33333333333333333333). If I add the first four arrays converted with the function above (convertCharToDec('3333') * 4), I end up with 3435973836.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen 32-126, yes. I am using only those, because I have to input the chars into a terminal and each has to be one byte long.

Comment: Is there any context to this question? It's all a little bit strange - where's the hash function come from? Why 4863101420 (is this a homework excercise?)? Why are you trying to build a target from subpermutations of a string? I ask because the context might provide some more information helpful to solving this.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen The hash function is in C. I am just reversing it's behaviour in python and trying to collide the hash, which is possible. I only have to find out one out of 20^94 combinations that matches it (many combinations should match, meaning I wouldn't have to test all 20^94). Since I wish I didn't have to go through all that, I wondered if I could shortcut it.

Answer (score 0):

Do some maths and you will find out that the final integer is equal to  A<sub>0</sub>×16<sup>6</sup> + A<sub>1</sub>×16<sup>4</sup> + A<sub>2</sub>×16<sup>2</sup> + A<sub>3</sub>, where A<sub>i</sub> = `sum([ord(the_whole_string[i + j]) for j in range(0, 20, 4)])`. It is a sum of 5 bytes, hence 32×5 ≤ A<sub>i</sub> ≤ 126×5.

Therefore, you could first try the values of A<sub>i</sub>'s, then for each of them try the combinations of the 5 bytes. This should greatly reduce the time of computation.

This works only if `format(ord(charInput[i]), "x")` returns a string of length 2 for any i.

---

Edit: Here is the math.

Example: `` 7]f`8^ga:_hb;`id<aje `` (This is one of the solution)

```
    7]f` -> int(375d6660, 16) = 37*16^6 + 5d*16^4 + 66*16^2 + 60
    8^ga -> int(385e6761, 16) = 38*16^6 + 5e*16^4 + 67*16^2 + 61
    :_hb -> int(3a5f6862, 16) = 3a*16^6 + 5f*16^4 + 68*16^2 + 62
    ;`id -> int(3b606964, 16) = 3b*16^6 + 60*16^4 + 69*16^2 + 63
    <aje -> int(3c616a65, 16) = 3c*16^6 + 61*16^4 + 6a*16^2 + 64
___________________________________________________________________
                                A0*16^6 + A1*16^4 + A2*16^2 + A3
```

Where `A0 = 37 + 38 + 3a + 3b + 3c`, `A1 = 5d + 5e + 5f + 60 + 61` etc.

Comment: format(ord(charInput[i]), "x") does return a string of length 2 for any i in an universe of 94 different i's (ascii 32 to 126).
I am actually adding 5 ints that were converted from 4 byte arrays of chars, not the opposite.
not sure yet how your solution would work though..

Comment: charInput[i] is just getting the char from the array, according to its position. This way, the array '3ab4' would have a charInput[0] value of '3'.